# How to capture multiple audio tracks independently on Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working with the Unity WebRTC plugin (available at https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/com.unity.webrtc) and I'm facing an issue regarding capturing multiple audio tracks.

Consider the WebRTC thing as an example, as it is not a problematic factor in this issue. I show it only because it is part of my project and it helps me to explain it better.

Specifically, I want to capture the Spanish version of the received WebRTC audio on one side, and the English version on another side. Currently, I'm using the OnAudioFilterRead() method to capture the audio in my scene, but this method doesn't provide the ability to filter mixer groups or similar functionalities, all the audio is mixed.

I have made a diagram which I think it is clearer where I am encountering a problem.

[image: diagram]

I can have the audio demuxed in two Mixer Groups, but I don't know how to get AudioMixerGroup.GetData() (for example) to get only the data of the mixer group, and not the main OAFR that gets all the audio listener info. I hope that it is clear.
Thank you!